# Securing DNS sub-domain delegation in Amazon Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Our company owns the domain `example.com`. We have a partner to whom we would like to delegate the subdomain `sub.example.com`. They would like to use Amazon's Route53 DNS service to manage this zone.

As I understand [the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html):

- Our partner must create a DNS zone named `sub.example.com` in Route53.
- Then we must update the NS records for the `sub.example.com` subdomain to our partner's DNS service name servers.

And voilà, the subdomain is delegated.

This process means that creating a DNS zone in Route53 "registers" the zone in one (or more) of Route53's name servers, regardless of whether or not the NS records for that domain actually point to these name servers (because the zone is created **before** the NS records).

Now, imagine Amazon's Route53 DNS service only has 1 name server (the following reasoning can easily be extended to N name servers). What happens when my partner tries to declare the DNS zone for himself if another company has already created its own `sub.example.com` zone **before** him?

Surely the DNS zone cannot be shared between both companies! So how does the Route53 mitigates the risk of malicious companies squatting DNS zones and preventing others from creating their own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigations, I found out that not all DNS services handle DNS zone collisions the same way.

OVH prevents a client from creating a DNS zone which has already been declared in their name servers by another client. This can be abused by any OVH customer, because they can create a DNS zone and prevent any other OVH customer from declaring the same zone later on.

Amazon Route53 owns multiple name servers, so they can guarantee that two identical DNS zones created by different customers are not declared in the same name servers. This can be abused the same way by creating 1 AWS account per name server group they own, and declaring the zone in each of these accounts, thus "filling up" all name servers and preventing other AWS accounts from creating the same zone. Although this could be made difficult to set up depending on the number of name servers AWS owns.

I'm not sure there is currently a standard way to prevent this sort of abuse. The only workaround I can think of for the DNS service would be to include the customer ID in the name server domains when creating a new zone, so that different customers can never cause a collision when creating the same zone. It doesn't look like something DNS services actually do.

Answer (score 0):

It's the NS delegation you described above which protects you from abuse.

If I am a DNS client and I want to lookup xxx.sub.example.com, then in principle I do something like this:

1. I check my configured list of root name servers;
2. I ask one of the root name servers for a name server for .com;
3. I ask the .com server for a name server for example.com;
4. I ask the example.com name server for a name server for sub.example.com;
5. Then I ask that name server to resolve xxx.sub.example.com.

So I can build an evil name server which serves up wrong answers for the sub.example.com domain but step #4 (which you control) means no real client will ever call me. (This isn't particular to Route53; just how DNS works)

Comment: Your explanation is not exactly what happens. 1) you typically use a recursive nameserver that does the iteration you list, and 2) at each step, historically, the whole name is checked, not label per label. This has changed with QNAME minimization

Comment: @lupin: I get that, but in the example I give the attacker uses the same DNS service as the client. There is no "evil name server", there are only name servers provided by the DNS service when creating the DNS zone.

Comment: This misses OP's concern; that if both user A and user B create `sub.example.com` zones on Route53, it might not know which one is "real". OP's self-answer is correct; Route53 handles this by assigning four *random* nameservers to each zone, even if they're the same FQDN, so user A would get a different set of nameservers than user B for `sub.example.com`. The actual owner of `example.com` would point them at the correct set of nameservers; the second set would exist, but never be actually used.